# [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot drop database "MyNewDatabase" because it is currently in use

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Now I have created two different connection for example I have a `.py` file called `connec` as the below code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc

# pyodbc connection connect to server
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    "driver={SQL Server};server=WINKPN-3B5JTT2\SMARTRNO_EXPRESS; database=master; trusted_connection=true",
    autocommit=True, Trusted_Connection='Yes')
crsr = conn.cursor()

# connect db (connect to database name) using SQL-Alchemy

engine = create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc://WINKPN-3B5JTT2\SMARTRNO_EXPRESS/MyNewDatabase?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
connection = engine.connect()
```

So now the first connection is related to the connection of the server, and the second one is the connection the database, the both connection works fine, but together I found the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/haroo501/PycharmProjects/ToolUpdated/app.py", line 16, in <module>
    delete_and_create_db.delete_database()
  File "C:\Users\haroo501\PycharmProjects\ToolUpdated\database\delete_and_create_db.py", line 9, in delete_database
    connec.crsr.execute(delete_bd_query)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot drop database "MyNewDatabase" because it is currently in use. (3702) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

When trying to run the below code:

```
from database import connec

def create_db():
    create_bd_query = "CREATE DATABASE MyNewDatabase"
    connec.crsr.execute(create_bd_query)

def delete_database():
    delete_bd_query = "DROP DATABASE MyNewDatabase"
    connec.crsr.execute(delete_bd_query
```

So I think there's a problem to use both connection or something, may be I put the two connection i `def` and call them when need, but I tried it doesn't work, Any one have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Don't connect to `MyNewDatabase`. Connect to `master`.

Comment: @BoarGules wow you saved me bro... thanks alot it works after I changed the connection string to this `'mssql+pyodbc://WINKPN-3B5JTT2\SMARTRNO_EXPRESS/master?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0'`

Comment: @BoarGules So now I figured problem it's creates a database called master, but that what I don't need, I need to when run the script just delete the database with name `MyNewDatabase` and create a again or even just delete all tables in that database and start doing the script I hope you could help me :)

Comment: It does not create a database called `master`. That is a SSL Server built-in database and you cannot drop it nor easily update it, nor should you try. I suggested you log into `master` because then you are sure of *not* being logged in to any user database. Doing `create database`, among other things, writes a row to table `master.dbo.databases`.